# Yii: Using an authorization hierarchy correctly

Tags: yii

I am attempting to validate if a user, who belongs to a company, can view an item that belongs to a company...in other words, if they are an employee they should be able to view the company's items.

I'm trying to follow the example provided here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

This is the code I generated (run one time):

```
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;
$auth->createOperation('viewItem','view an item');
$bizRule = 'return User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getId())->company->id==$params["item"]->company->id';
$task=$auth->createTask('companyOwnedItem','view a company-owned item',$bizRule);
$task->addChild('viewItem');
```

This is the code in main.php:

```
        'authManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
        'connectionID'=>'db',
```

This is the authorization piece used in my controller:

```
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('companyOwnedItem',array('item'=>$item))) {
    echo 'YES';
} else echo 'NO';
```

I always get 'NO' on the screen.

However if I use this code:

```
if (User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getId())->company->id==$item->company->id)
```

Then I get 'YES' on the screen.  What am I doing wrong and how do I use Yii's built-in authManager to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following and it worked:

In my config:

```
'authManager'=>array(
   'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
   'connectionID'=>'db',
   'defaultRoles'=>array('authenticated'),
   'showErrors'=>true,
),
```

My authManager code:

```
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;
    $bizRule = 'return User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getId())->company->id==$params["item"]->company->id;';
    $auth->createOperation('companyOwnedItem','view a company-owned item',$bizRule);
    $role = $auth->createRole('authenticated');
    $role->addChild('companyOwnedItem');
```

Then in my controller:

```
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('companyOwnedItem',array('item'=>$item))) {
  echo 'YES';
} else {echo 'NO';}
```

And it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is that the item in items array isn't working properly. Have you turned on debugging for your auth manager? Forgot the property, but there is one to turn on in case of bizRule errors.

Other than that, it looks right. Also, FYI, after Yii 1.1.11, there is a $param['userId'] option so that you don't need to look up the current user's ID.

Comment: That got me one step closer, I was missing a semicolon at the end of my bizrule.  `$bizRule = 'return User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getId())->company->id==$params["item"]->company->id;';` But it's still not validating.  Could it be that I've defined my roles incorrectly?

Comment: It runs the results inside of eval(), so it might be worth setting everything up and checking it that way.  Or, if you've got Xdebug and a PHP debugger, it's quite helpful to see how things are set up / how they work if you just step through it.  I'm using PhpStorm and it works great.

Comment: Your suggestion to add `showErrors=>true` in my authManager config helped me to test that the bizRule was being applied, but I posted a solution that works. Thanks for the suggestions.